# 'Sorry. You are not using Tor' - Strange issue 72.52.91.18/19

Tags: anonymity, exit-relays, onion-routing

> ADD: ^^^ mmm I don't think it's the same. In that question they talk
>   about a **false negative**, but judging from the results of my
>   port-scan, and considering that more than 2 weeks passed, it looks
>   like there's no Tor-like service running on them. Therefore this seems
>   to be a legitimate negative, not a false one imho.

---

A strange issue started happening to me since about 2 weeks ago:
I started noticing TBB home screens like this one:

[image: Sorry. You are not using Tor.]

The first time I thought it was some sort of synchronization problem between the beginning of activity of a new exit node in the network and its official adding to the Tor directory.  So I just reloaded Tor and let it go.
But then a few days later it happened another time, with a very-similar-but-different IP that came from the same network I guess (the first was 72.52.91.18, while the other 72.52.91.19). After that, another couple of times it showed up with the same initial IP. So I started being dubious,  and I decided to find out what could it be when I had a free moment. So just a few minutes ago I took some info:

- Their ISP seems to be Hurricane Electric. Its servers are from the same network, located near Livermore (California). Here's my whois: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6254724/
- I also did a nmap, to verify whether they really had some kind of Tor service running, and it doesn't seem so.

---

```
Nmap scan report for 72.52.91.18
Host is up (0.26s latency). Not shown: 994 filtered ports    

PORT    STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp  open   ssh
25/tcp  closed smtp
53/tcp  closed domain
80/tcp  closed http
179/tcp closed bgp
443/tcp closed https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 387.11 seconds
```

---

```
Nmap scan report for 72.52.91.19
Host is up (0.26s latency). Not shown: 807 closed ports, 191 filtered ports

PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
8888/tcp open  sun-answerbook

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 117.63 seconds
```

Hilariously, just after my nmapping, I ran TBB and... there was it again, same IP!
So I made a screenshot and decided to share it with you.

What do you think?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does check.torproject.org sometimes tell me I'm not using Tor, when I am?](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/190/why-does-check-torproject-org-sometimes-tell-me-im-not-using-tor-when-i-am)

Comment: Uhh I don't think so, that post is about a false negative, but... after my port-scan, it seems that this couple of IPs have nothing to do with tor. Also, the first time happened 2 weeks ago, the last one just 9 hours ago, with the same IP: this means that they are not part of the tor network.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ExoneraTor](https://metrics.torproject.org/exonerator.html) to find out if a particular IP was running a Tor relay at a particular time. For example, according to ExoneraTor 
72.52.91.19 was running an exit node on 2013-10-13. This lends support to the theory that the check error you saw may have been a false negative.

Comment: Sorry but I have 2 concerns. 1) The last time it happened was exactly after my port-scan, that's about 18hours ago - that's where the screenshot comes from - and ExoneraTor tells it wasn't running at that time.

2) Why an added exit-node that's pretty unstable (alternatively up and down within very short intervals) gains so quickly the "quality score" needed to become part of a circuit?